# How to consider few parameters in method

Tags: java, file, io

I have my own implementation of SimpleFileVisitor with a visitFile method.
I wonder how can i perform more precise search, if there are more than only one parameter. Here what i mean

```
public class SearchFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>
{
    private String partOfName;
    private String partOfContent;
    private int minSize;
    private int maxSize;
    private List<Path> foundFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setPartOfName(String partOfName)
    {
        this.partOfName = partOfName;
    }

    public void setPartOfContent(String partOfContent)
    {
        this.partOfContent = partOfContent;
    }

    public void setMinSize(int minSize)
    {
        this.minSize = minSize;
    }

    public void setMaxSize(int maxSize)
    {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public List<Path> getFoundFiles()
    {
        return foundFiles;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException
    {
        if(partOfName != null && file.toString().contains(partOfName))
        {
           foundFiles.add(file);
        }
        else if(partOfContent != null)
            {
                try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file))
                {
                    while(scanner.hasNextLine())
                    {
                        String line = scanner.nextLine();
                        if(line.contains(partOfContent))
                        {
                            foundFiles.add(file);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         else if(file.toFile().length() < maxSize)
         {
             foundFiles.add(file);
         }
         else if(file.toFile().length() > minSize)
         {
             foundFiles.add(file);
         }
        return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
    }
}
```

The main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        SearchFileVisitor searchFileVisitor = new SearchFileVisitor();

        searchFileVisitor.setPartOfName("John");
        searchFileVisitor.setPartOfContent("be or not to be?");
        searchFileVisitor.setMinSize(500);
        searchFileVisitor.setMaxSize(10000);

        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("D:/SecretFolder"), searchFileVisitor);

        List<Path> foundFiles = searchFileVisitor.getFoundFiles();
        for (Path file : foundFiles)
        {
            System.out.println(file);
        }
    }
```

So, if i set only partOfName it should relay only on it. But if beside it i also set partOfContent and say maxSize, it simultaneously should relay on 3 parameters so far. And consequently if there are 4 par it should relay on four and add to the List, if the object satisfies all the criteria. How can i do that?(Without damn boolean flags)

Comment: There are different approaches, one of them will be to split class `SearchFileVisitor` to a few different classes based on the search criteria. The have a dispatcher that calls the right class according to the arguments it was invoked with.

Comment: Chances are you can't; you need to know if options are set. But you can wrap up that aspect of the walker in any number of ways so the mainline code remains clear.

Comment: Should the minSize/maxSize parameters include files that are exactly that size? In other words, checking the size with <= and >=? It seems clearer that way.

Answer (score 1):

You should structure the logic as "parameter is disabled OR file passes parameter check" for each parameter.

First, use default values to indicate a parameter is disabled:

```
private String partOfName = null;
private String partOfContent = null;
private int minSize = -1;
private int maxSize = -1;
```

Then you can use a single if statement, with the partOfContent check in a separate method to keep things simple:

```
@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    if ((partOfName == null || file.toString().contains(partOfName))
            && (partOfContent == null || fileContains(file, partOfContent))
            && (maxSize < 0 || file.toFile().length() < maxSize)
            && (minSize < 0 || file.toFile().length() > minSize)) {
        foundFiles.add(file);
    }
    return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
}

private static boolean fileContains(Path file, String partOfContent) throws IOException {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (line.contains(partOfContent)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note this just describes the general idea. On a review I'd probably reconsider class and method names.

I'd introduce a "Predicate" and describe the expected result in a declarative way using decorators.

The interface of the `Predicate` would look like this:

```
public interface Predicate {
    boolean matches (Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs);
}
```

Each instance only matches a single criteria like the name and delegates to another predicate for additional tests:

```
public final class Named implements Predicate{

   private final Predicate mDelegate;
   private final String mPartOfName;

   public Named(String partOfName, Predicate delegate)
   {
       mPartOfName = partOfName;
       mDelegate = delegate;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean matches(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
   {
       return file.toString().contains(mPartOfName) && mDelegate.matches(file, attrs);
   }
}
```

Or the maximum size:

```
public final class MaxSized implements Predicate{

   private final Predicate mDelegate;
   private final int mMaxSize;

   public MaxSized(int maxSize, Predicate delegate)
   {
       mMaxSize = maxSize;
       mDelegate = delegate;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean matches(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
   {
       return file.toFile().length() < mMaxSize && mDelegate(file, attrs);
   }
}
```

A "match all" predicate looks as simple as this:

```
public final class All implements Predicate{
   @Override
   public boolean matches(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
   {
       return true;
   }
}
```

The `SeachFileVisitor` would shrink down to this:

```
public final class SearchFileVisitor extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>{
    private final List<Path> foundFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Predicate mPredicate;

    public SearchFileVisitor(Predicate predicate){
        mPredicate = predicate;
    }


    public List<Path> getFoundFiles() {
        return foundFiles;
    }

    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if (mPredicate.matches(file, attrs)) {
            foundFiles.add(file);
        }
    }
}
```

and you would set it up like this:

```
SearchFileVisitor searchFileVisitor =
    new SearchFileVisitor(
        new MaxSized(10000,
            new Named("John",
                new All())));
```

The predicate can be read as "return `All` elements that are `Named` like `"John"` and have a maximum size of `10000`". You can also read it forward like this: "A size constrained and name constrained version of a match-all predicate".

- The predicates are immutable, so no side effects in concurrent environments.
- All classes are short and simple and easy to test.
- New predicates can be added without modifying existing code.
- No "damn boolean flags"

Answer (score 0):

You should use Stream<Path> instead of FileVisitor<Path> like this.

```
static boolean contains(Path path, String partOfContent) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path)) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (line.contains(partOfContent)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Path> results = Files.walk(Paths.get("D:/SecretFolder"))
        .filter(path -> Files.isRegularFile(path))
        .filter(path -> path.toString().contains("Jhon"))
        .filter(path -> contains(path, "be or not to be?"))
        .filter(path -> path.toFile().length() >= 500)
        .filter(path -> path.toFile().length() <= 10000)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    results.stream()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

If you don't want to check minimum file size, delete the line `.filter(path -> path.toFile().length() >= 500)`.